# what is the mechanism by which a python virtual environment (venv) limits the module search path to the local directory?

Tags: python, python-venv

What exactly does setting up and activating a virtual environment do? From what I gather it will change the module search path environment variable for the directory it is installed in? Thus, any subdirectory modules which attempt to import a module will be forced to look in the local sites package folder rather than the global one (as long as the venv is active).

I see that if I activate the venv and run pip list I no longer get the global package list but the local one. However, I can't seem to find a local sites-packages directory...

Comment: They aren't not "forced". You can always edit `sys.path` or `PYTHONPATH` values. Also, by default, venv are created with access to the "global" modules (`venv --system-site-packages`)

Comment: [_PEP 405_](https://peps.python.org/pep-0405/) can also provide some insight.

Answer (score 1):

"what is the mechanism"/"what exactly does ... activating" -- i.e. what does the code do?

You can find an explanation in official docs:
https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/venv.html#how-venvs-work

And you can dive into the [sourcecode of `<venv>/bin/activate`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/venv/scripts/common/activate) to see what it does. It's not a complex script, and I suggest trying to read through it and asking separate questions about any specific parts you don't understand.